# Does eclipse must depend on one of the build tool like ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

If no ant or other build tool, can eclipse itself handle large project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While eclipse can handle large projects, it is in most cases necessary to use an IDE-independant build tool, like ant or maven:

- should be able to produce deployable artifact with one command
- should not be tied to a particular IDE. Team members may choose different IDEs
- should be usable from command line and continuous integration tools

Comment: advisable? I'd say it is irresponsible not to if the project is of any value.

Comment: @Jens Schauder yeah, I was too mild with the wording. Improved it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Without a build tool you lose:

- reproducability: Builds from your machine will likely look different from you coworkers. You might have a different plugin installed, a different JDK configured ... a build tool will minimize these dependencies.
- continuous integration: No way to do that without a build too.
- IDE independence. What if somebody wants to use Netbeans or IDEA because it would help tremendously with the next task?